# JQuery get parent of element in result of query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to select a number of td elements. For each element, I need to use the parent() function to get the id of the tr element that contains it.

I understand that if I have a single element, I can simply do `element.parent("tr").attr("id")`, but how do I do the same for multiple objects?

```
$("td.staff-col").append(`
    <form>Start time:<input type='text' name='start_time'>End time: 
        <input type='text' name='end_time'>
        <button onclick="assign(${this.parent("tr").attr("id")})">Add</button>
    </form>
`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Sushil said should work but here is an example that should clearfy it for you

```js
function assign(element){
console.log($(element).closest('tr').attr('id'));

return false;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr id="1">
   <td>
   <form>Start time:<input type='text' name='start_time'>End time: 
        <input type='text' name='end_time'>
        <button onclick=" return assign(this)">Add</button>
    </form>
     </td>
     </tr>
  
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onclick="assign(${this.parent("tr").attr("id")})` this code from `<button onclick="assign(${this.parent("tr").attr("id")})">Add</button>`
and add this below code

```js
$('td').off().on('click', function(){
  var id=$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="tr1">
   <td>hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
   <td>hello hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr3">
   <td>hello hello hello</td>
</tr>
```

**Note**: The snippet is an example for your solution. You can append your `HTML` and add this click event somewhere on your `js` code.

Comment: I do need a button, though, as the assign function does an api call, using the id of the tr element as part of the data

Comment: @Alex try adding this method, if it doesn't work please let me know.

Comment: @Alex `$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');` should work for you.